# Can I have only two functions to handle all groups ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

To explain my question I should provide some introduction.

I have about 5, 6 groups of properties in My ViewModel in real interface,
that's why this example is simplified:

```
Album {
    title: 'string'
    artists: [{…}, {…}],
    genres: [{…}, {…}]
}
```

Objects in artists/genres arrays are identical by structure:

```
item = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'string'
}
```

For similar groups of properties I have similar to each other functions:

```
self.AddArtist();
self.RemoveArtist(artist);
self.AddGenre();
self.RemoveGenre(genre);
```

**Qustion:** Can I have only two functions like `AddItem(array)/RemoveItem(array, item)` to
handle operations with all groups of properties of ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such structure:

```
var Album = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.title = 'string';

    self.groups = {
        artists: ko.observableArray(),
        genres: ko.observableArray()        
    };    

    self.addItem = function(groupName, item) {
        self.groups[groupName].push(item);
    };

    self.removeItem = function(groupName, item) {
        self.groups[groupName].remove(item);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
album = new Album();
album.addItem('artists', 'test');
```